# Passing arguments and default arguments in nested functions

Tags: r, scope, nested, parameter-passing, evaluation

I have a function, `x_pdf`, that is supposed to calculate  x*dfun(x|params) where dfun is a probability density function and params is a list of named parameters. It is defined inside of another function,  `int_pdf`, that is supposed to integrate `x_pdf` between specified bounds:

```
int_pdf <- function(lb = 0, ub = Inf, dfun, params){
  x_pdf <- function(X, dfun, params){X * do.call(function(X){dfun(x=X)}, params)}
    out <- integrate(f = x_pdf, lower=lb, upper=ub, subdivisions = 100L)
  out
}
```

Note that, given my defaults for the lower and upper bound of integration, I expect that when the function is run with only the params specified it will return the mean of x.

I have a second function, `int_gb2`, that is a wrapper for `int_pdf` intended to specialize it to the generalized beta disttribution of the second kind.

```
library(GB2)

int_gb2 <- function(lb = 0, ub = Inf, params){
  int_pdf(lb, ub, dfun = dgb2, params = get("params"))
}
```

When I run the function as follows:

```
GB2_params   <-  list(shape1 = 3.652, scale = 65797, shape2 = 0.3, shape3 = 0.8356)
int_gb2(params = GB2_params)
```

I get:

```
 Error in do.call(what = function(X) { : 
  argument "params" is missing, with no default
```

I have spent multiple hours tweaking this, and I have nanaged to generate tome alternative error messages, but always with respect to a missing x, X, or params.

Comment: Maybe `integrate(f = x_pdf, lower=lb, upper=ub, params, subdivisions = 100L)`. Your call to `integrate` is not passing `params` to the integrand.

Comment: Sorry, it must be a *named* argument, `out <- integrate(f = x_pdf, lower=lb, upper=ub, params=params, subdivisions = 100L)`. And the error is now different: `Error in (function (X)  :   unused arguments (shape1 = 3.652, scale = 65797, shape2 = 0.3, shape3 = 0.8356)`.

Comment: @andrewH Could you show that `int_pdf` works with `GB2_params` when called directly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be two problems here, both related to passing arguments: in the first one there are too many arguments being passed, and in the second one, too few.

First off, in your `x_pdf` definition, you use an anonymous function that takes a single argument (`function(X){dfun(x=X)}`), but you also try to pass additional arguments (the `params` list) to said anonymous function with `do.call`, which will throw an error. That part should instead look something like this:

```
do.call(dfun, c(list(x = X), params))
```

Now, you've defined `x_pdf` to *require* 3 arguments: `X`, `dfun`, and `params`; but when you call `x_pdf` with `integrate` you're not passing the `dfun` and `params` arguments, which again will throw an error. You could get around that by passing `dfun` and `params`, too:

```
integrate(f = x_pdf, lower=lb, upper=ub, subdivisions = 100L, dfun, params)
```

But perhaps a neater solution would be to just remove the additional arguments from the definition of `x_pdf` (since `dfun` and `params` are already defined in the enclosing environment), for a more compact result:

```
int_pdf <- function(lb = 0, ub = Inf, dfun, params){
  x_pdf <- function(X) X * do.call(dfun, c(list(x = X), params))
  integrate(f = x_pdf, lower = lb, upper = ub, subdivisions = 100L)
}
```

With this definition of `int_pdf`, everything should work as you expect:

```
GB2_params <- list(shape1 = 3.652, scale = 65797, shape2 = 0.3, shape3 = 0.8356)
int_gb2(params = GB2_params)
#> Error in integrate(f = x_pdf, lower = lb, upper = ub, subdivisions = 100L):
#>   the integral is probably divergent
```

Oh. Are the example parameters missing a decimal point from the `scale` argument?

```
GB2_params$scale <- 6.5797
int_gb2(params = GB2_params)
#> 4.800761 with absolute error < 0.00015
```

---

### Extra bits

We could also use some functional programming to create a function factory to make it easy to create functions for finding moments other than the first one:

```r
moment_finder <- function(n, c = 0) {
  function(f, lb = -Inf, ub = Inf, params = NULL, ...) {
    integrand <- function(x) {
      (x - c) ^ n * do.call(f, c(list(x = x), params))
    }
    integrate(f = integrand, lower = lb, upper = ub, ...)
  }
}
```

To find the mean, you would just create a function to find the first moment:

```r
find_mean <- moment_finder(1)

find_mean(dnorm, params = list(mean = 2))
#> 2 with absolute error < 1.2e-05
find_mean(dgb2, lb = 0, params = GB2_params)
#> 4.800761 with absolute error < 0.00015
```

For variance, you'd have to find the second central moment:

```r
find_variance <- function(f, ...) {
  mean <- find_mean(f, ...)$value
  moment_finder(2, c = mean)(f, ...)
}

find_variance(dnorm, params = list(mean = 2, sd = 4))
#> 16 with absolute error < 3.1e-07
find_variance(dgb2, lb = 0, params = GB2_params)
#> 21.67902 with absolute error < 9.2e-05
```

Alternatively we could just generalise further, and find the expected value
of any transformation, rather than just moments:

```r
ev_finder <- function(transform = identity) {
  function(f, lb = -Inf, ub = Inf, params = NULL, ...) {
    integrand <- function(x) {
      transform(x) * do.call(f, c(list(x = x), params))
    }
    integrate(f = integrand, lower = lb, upper = ub, ...)
  }
}
```

Now `moment_finder` would be a special case:

```r
moment_finder <- function(n, c = 0) {
  ev_finder(transform = function(x) (x - c) ^ n)
}
```

Created on 2018-02-17 by the [reprex package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

If you've read this far, you might also enjoy [Advanced R](https://adv-r.hadley.nz/functional-programming.html) by Hadley Wickham.

---

### More extra bits

@andrewH I understood from your comment that you might be looking to find means of truncated distributions, e.g. find the mean for the part of the distribution above the mean of the entire distribution.

To do that, it's not enough to just integrate the first moment's integrand up from the mean value: you'll also have to rescale the PDF in the integrand, to make it a proper PDF again, after the truncation (make up for the lost probability mass, if you will, in a "hand wave-y" figure of speech). You can do that by dividing with the integral of the original PDF over the support of the truncated one.

Here's the code to better convey what I mean:

```r
library(purrr)
library(GB2)

find_mass <- moment_finder(0)
find_mean <- moment_finder(1)

GB2_params <- list(shape1 = 3.652, scale = 6.5797, shape2 = 0.3, shape3 = 0.8356)
dgb2p <- invoke(partial, GB2_params, ...f = dgb2)  # pre-apply parameters

# Mean value
(mu <- find_mean(dgb2p, lb = 0)$value)
#> [1] 4.800761

# Mean for the truncated distribution below the mean
(lower_mass <- find_mass(dgb2p, lb = 0, ub = mu)$value)
#> [1] 0.6108409
(lower_mean <- find_mean(dgb2p, lb = 0, ub = mu)$value / lower_mass)
#> [1] 2.40446

# Mean for the truncated distribution above the mean
(upper_mass <- find_mass(dgb2p, lb = mu)$value)
#> [1] 0.3891591
(upper_mean <- find_mean(dgb2p, lb = mu)$value / upper_mass)
#> [1] 8.562099

lower_mean * lower_mass + upper_mean * upper_mass
#> [1] 4.800761
```

Comment: This is a great answer and I'm going to accept it, but I would be grateful for your thoughts on the following: the GB2 package also provides  functions for the mean and other moments. My parameters should yield a crude approximation of US household income in 1997. Using the moment functions:  do.call(moment.gb2, c(k=0, GB2_params)) = 1,   do.call(moment.gb2, c(k=1, GB2_params)) = 48007.61, and 2nd & 3rd moments also exist; 4th does not. Running your revised version on the one-tailed integrals around the mean, both exist, but the upper tail has an impossible value: 33320, below lb. Puzzling.

Comment: Just to be clear, you're referring to calculating `find_mean(dgb2, lb = 0, ub = 48007.61, params = GB2_params) = 14687` and `find_mean(dgb2, lb = 48007.61, params = GB2_params) = 33320`?

Comment: If so, then that makes perfect sense: since calculating those two integrals is essentially just partitioning the full 0 to `Inf` integral into the part below the mean and above the mean, it follows that the sum of the integrals must equal the mean. (As `find_mean(dgb2, 0, Inf, ...)` would just give the mean)

Comment: I thought out loud a bit further in the body of the answer. Did I follow what you were after?

Comment: Yes, that is theparameterization in your comment is the same one I used..

Comment: What I am trying to do with this integral of x*pdf(x) is estimate conditional means of income ranges, given the parameters of the distribution. So if I correctly understand  what I am doing, the 0 to 48008 mean should be the mean income for people with incomes below 48008, and the 48008 to Inf mean should be the mean income for those above 48008, So I expect the mean of the 2, weighted by their population shares, to be the population mean. But I get 33320 as the mean for people with incomes above 48008. That can't be right. Is this the wrong expression  for a conditional mean?

Comment: For this sort of "self-conditional" mean you're really thinking about truncated distributions, which is what I was trying to explain. If you just integrate `x * pdf(x)` in two parts then by definition the sum of the two parts is the mean. That is, to find the conditional expectations you have to divide the partial integrals by their respective population shares, or "probability mass" as I called it. I expanded the updated bit to print out some more numbers to illustrate.

Comment: To re-iterate, in order to find an expectation by integrating `x * f(x)` over an area, `f(x)` must be a PDF in that area (positive and integrates to 1). If you take a PDF with a support of (0,Inf), it won't be a PDF on any other interval than (0, Inf), because it doesn't integrate to 1 anymore.

Comment: This is a terrific answer and I wish I could accept it twice, or three times even. You answered not only my original question. But also solved other problems I did not even know I had. Many, many thanks. Dividing the integral in my original function by the integral of the pdf over the same range gets me the right results. I’m still having some convergence problems, but I will address those in a separate question.